# How can I sort this?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this JSON file that has this structure.

```
{

    country: {

        state: [{



            city: [{

                nest_1: {


                    nest_2: {


                        borough: [{
                                id: 1
                            },
                            {
                                id: 8
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2
                            }
                        ]


                    }

                }


            }];

        }];


    }

}
```

Angular get the data like this

```
    this.http
    .get(this.datajson).subscribe(all_data => {
      this.allData = [all_data as any];
    });
```

How can I isolate the array **borough** and sort that array by the id ?

I would like that I get access to that particular array so I could filter before the data gets to the HTML. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties of objects with dot notation (usually) and elements of arrays with bracket notation.

After getting to the array, you can call `sort`, passing a callback that subtracts the ids.

```js
const all_data={country:{state:[{city:[{nest_1:{nest_2:{borough:[{id:1},{id:8},{id:5},{id:2}]}}}]}]}};
all_data.country.state[0].city[0].nest_1.nest_2.borough.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(all_data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: The data comes back from HTTP Get. There is no direct access but through the Get Method.

Comment: @allforthenoob What does that have to do with sorting the array? Just sort it after you get the response.

Comment: There is noway to call the array all_data is a function in my case. There is no explicit mention of the array. In an **ngOnInit** is this code `this.http
    .get(this.datajson).subscribe(all_data => {
      this.allData = [all_data as any];
    });`

Comment: allData is type definitions and all_data is the function that the subscription is passed to

Comment: Are you sure `all_data` is a function? It's the first parameter of the subscribe callback, not the callback function itself. What do you get if you log it? @allforthenoob

Comment: Apologies, it's an Object. Regardless of that i can't chain anything to it. this `all_data.country.state[0].city[0].nest_1.nest_2.borough` won't work. Error is, country does not exist on type Object.

Comment: @allforthenoob Then you're not showing the actual data structure in your question. Please post exactly what `all_data` looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253753/discussion-between-allforthenoob-and-unmitigated).